# Interoperable access authorization request for google cloud storage fails with 'signature does not match' error

Tags: php, http, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a bucket on GCS using API v1.0 (interoperable mode) in PHP but I'm getting a 'signature does not match' error response.

Here's what I'm doing:

---

```
$access_id = "GOOGxxxxxx";
$secret_key = "xyxyxyxyx/xyxyxyxyx";
$bucket = "random_bucket_name";
$url = 'https://'.$bucket.'commondatastorage.googleapis.com';
$timestamp  = date("r");

$canonicalizedResources = "/ HTTP 1.1";
$stringToSign = utf8_encode("PUT "."\n"."\n"."\n".$canonicalizedResources);
$signature  = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1",$stringToSign,$secret_key,true));
$authSignature = $access_id.":".$signature;

$headers = array('Host: '.$bucket.'.commondatastorage.googleapis.com',
           'Date: '.$timestamp, 'x-goog-api-version: 1', 
           'x-goog-project-id: xxxyyyxy','Content-Length: 0',
           'Authorization: GOOG1 '.$authSignature);

$c   = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
$xml = curl_exec($c);
```

---

And here's the response that I get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you 
   provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
  <StringToSign>
   GET


   Sat, 03 Mar 2012 14:56:53 -0800
   x-goog-api-version:1
   x-goog-project-id:xxxyyyxy
   /random_bucket_name/
  </StringToSign>
 </Error>
```

---

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Here's Google's documentation on this: 
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#putbucket

One thing I noticed is that even though I specify "PUT" in the "stringToSign" variable ... the response says that I used "GET" ... ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here:

- Your canonicalized resource should be "/bucket/", not "/ HTTP 1.1".
- You need to include your two custom headers (x-goog-version and x-goog-project-id) in the string to sign.
- The string to sign must include the timestamp sent in the Date: header.
- You need to set CURLOPT_PUT so that curl knows to send a PUT request, rather than the default GET request (that's why your error response alludes to a GET request).

Here's a corrected version of your code, which I tested and used to create a new bucket:

```
<?php
  $access_id = "REDACTED";
  $secret_key = "REDACTED";
  $bucket = "your-bucket";
  $url = 'https://'.$bucket.'commondatastorage.googleapis.com';
  $timestamp  = date("r");
  $version_header = "x-goog-api-version:1";
  $project_header = "x-goog-project-id:REDACTED";
  $canonicalizedResources = "/".$bucket."/";
  $stringToSign = utf8_encode("PUT\n\n\n".$timestamp."\n".$version_header."\n".$project_header."\n".$canonicalizedResources);
  $signature  = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1",$stringToSign,$secret_key,true));
  $authSignature = $access_id.":".$signature;

  $headers = array('Host: '.$bucket.'.commondatastorage.googleapis.com',
                   'Date: '.$timestamp, $version_header,
                   $project_header,'Content-Length: 0',
                   'Authorization: GOOG1 '.$authSignature);

  $c   = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PUT, TRUE);
  $xml = curl_exec($c);
  print($xml);
?>
```

P.S. All the details on HMAC authentication for Google Cloud Storage are provided here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference/v1/developer-guidev1#authentication

Comment: Thanks Marc, I did try this out and the request fails silently; I'm not getting an error response nor is a bucket getting created.

I will delve into the documentation some more to see where I'm going wrong.

Thanks again for your response.